# Need help plotting a wavefunction generated from a sum of eigenstates

Tags: plotting, manipulate, fourier-analysis

I am a beginner in Mathematica. I am trying to plot the time evolution of a non-eigenstate wavefunction as a sum of eigenstates.

So I start with an eigenstate of an infinite square well, then expand the well rapidly to twice its initial size, then I want to plot how the wavefunction evolves.

I got this error:
[image]

I am going to try to use `Manipulate` to evolve it after my `Plot` works

Comment: Please paste your code so respondents can experiment with it.

Comment: At the first glance, I would say you have to clear the symbol ``x`` with ``Clear[x]``.

Comment: @Syed, I tried to paste my code, but things got messy. 
Cn[n_] := \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(L1\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(2\), 
SqrtBox[\(L1\ L2\)]] Sin[\ 
\*FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(L1\)] x] Sin[n\ 
\*FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(L2\)] x] \[DifferentialD]x\)\);
Something like that. How do I paste the code correctly?

Comment: I tried the 'Clear[x]' but it didn't work. This time Mathematica keeps running and I had to abort the evaluation

Comment: To past your code cleanly, first convert it to `InputForm`.  Also, have you tried saving your notebook, closing and reopening  Mathematica, and then loading and running your notebook.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message it looks like the variable $x$ has a value, 0.000204.  What's happening is `ψ2[0]` is getting evaluated for each value of the plot variable, $x$.  The value of $x$ is then being substituted into the expression for $c_n$ before the integration is carried out.  That may be just as well, because the infinite sum is not going to finish evaluating anyway.

Let's make three changes.  First, let's use $\xi $ as the variable of integration for the $c_n$'s.  Second, let's use memoization to avoid recalculating each $c_n$ for every value of the plot variable.  Third, let's use only a finite number of terms in the summation.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
L1 = 1; L2 = 2; h = 1; m = 1;
nmax = 12;

ϕ[L_, n_, x_] := Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n π /L x]
En[L_, n_] := n^2 π^2 h^2/(2 m L^2)
Cn[n_] := Cn[n] = Integrate[2/Sqrt[L1 L2] Sin[π/L1 ξ] Sin[n π/L2 ξ], {ξ, 0, L1}]
```

Note the memoization in the previous line.  That ensures each $c_n$ is only calculated once.  Now define the *finite* summation and evaluate it at $t=0$

```
ψ2[t_] := Sum[Cn[n] ϕ[L2, n, x] Exp[-I En[L2, n]/h t], {n, 1, nmax}]
f = ψ2[0];
```

We can plot $f$ with `Plot[f, {x, 0, 10}]`, which gives

[image]

The squiggly baseline in the plot is due to using only 12 terms in the summation.  It may be interesting to look at how much time it takes to evaluate `Plot[f,{x,0,10}]` compared to `Plot[ψ2[0],{x,0,10}]`.

The following timing results were obtained using `nmax = 12`

```
Plot[f, {x, 0, 10}] // Timing // First       (*  0.042195  *)
Plot[ψ2[0], {x, 0, 10}] // Timing // First   (*  0.414601  *)
```

The timing results lend credence to the earlier statement that the summation for `ψ2[0]` is being re-evaluated for each value of the plot variable.

#### Using Manipulate

Here is a `Manipulate` that uses a common programming style and gives good (quick) results even for larger values of $n_{max}$

```
g = Norm[ψ2[t]]^2;
Manipulate[
 Plot[g /. t -> λ, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 2.5}}],
 {λ, 0, 10}]
```

There are knowledgeable explanations in this forum of why the `t -> λ` replacement is necessary, but I don't remember any of them.  As a rule, I try do as much of the calculation as possible outside of the `Manipulate` and then use the "slider replacement" technique inside the `Manipulate`.

Comment: Thanks! I have managed to make it evolve in time using 'Manipulate'.

But I have a few questions, why can't I use `f` in 'Manipulate'? I tried this 'Manipulate[Plot[Norm[f]^2, {x, 0, 2}], {t, 0, 10}]' but the graph stays still when I move the slider. I had to use 'Manipulate[Plot[Norm[\psi2 [t]]^2, {x, 0, 2}], {t, 0, 10}]' instead.

Comment: `Manipulate` can be tricky to use.  I can't give a good explanation of why some code does not work, but I have seen good explanations in this forum.  It is possible to define $f$ outside the `Manipulate` and then use the "slider replacement" technique, as I call it.  Please see the new "Using Manipulate" section of the answer.

Comment: Thanks again :) . Can you tell me how to paste code correctly?

Comment: @ForacleFunacle My copy/paste procedure: In MMA, (1) select cells, (2) Shift-Ctrl-I to convert to input form, (3) Ctrl-C to copy.  In SE editor pane, (a) Ctrl-V to paste, (b) select the inserted code block text, (c) click menu icon { } to indent the code block, (d) click menu icon $\alpha\beta$ to convert greek letters, etc, (e) edit the code for readability.  Back in MMA (4) Ctrl-Z to undo the effect of Shift-Ctrl-I.  See [MMA.SE Meta site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=copy+code) for more. Don't miss [this answer](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/22158)